# Azure AD B2C updating users sign in names results in error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

When I'm trying to update the list of `SignInNames`, I get the error:
`Resource <EMAIL ADDRESS> does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present`.

```
var currentUser = await GetUserByUserNameAsync(userId); // this gets the user
var signinNames = currentUser.SignInNames.ToList();
signinNames.Add(new SignInName
{
   Type = "emailAddress",
   Value = newEmailaddress
});
var data = new B2CChangeEmailAddressData()
{
    SignInNames = signinNames
};
var response = await _graphApi.SendAsync(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), $"users/{userId}", null, data);
```

And then it returns the error.
I use comparable code to update the password, that works fine. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did was:

- I got the user by its sign in name (the email address)
- I tried to edit the user by using the sign in name

The first is possible, but the second isn't. I had to update the user by using the `ObjectId`. So the code should be:

```
var currentUser = await GetUserByUserNameAsync(userId);
var path = $"users/{currentUser.ObjectId}";
var signinNames = new List<SignInName>();
signinNames.Add(new SignInName
{
     Type = "emailAddress",
     Value = newEmailaddress
});
var data = new B2CChangeEmailAddressData()
{
     SignInNames = signinNames
};

var response = await _graphApi.SendAsync(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), path, null, data);
```